# Tomcat Keeps Running After Integration Test Finished

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, integration-testing

*I'm sorry for the complete rewrite in case you read this earlier...*

I migrated a project to a Spring-Boot project and executing an integration test results in Tomcat running after it finished. This is true for running it in Eclipse and Maven. The downside of Maven is that the building process discontinues and only Ctrl+C helps, which actually also stops Maven.

Here's the plug-in stuff from the `pom.xml`:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>${java.version}</source>
      <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>at.a1.iap.spagat.aggregator</finalName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <!-- required to make four soapui-test-classes work -->
          <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*ITest.java</include>
          </includes>
          <!-- no need to exclude and if you exclude no tests will be
            run <excludes> <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude> </excludes> -->
        </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>verify</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <mappings>
        <mapping>
          <namespace>http://www.agama.tv/ws/emp</namespace>
          <targetPackage>at.a1.iap.spagat.aggregator.external.agama</targetPackage>
        </mapping>
      </mappings>

      <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</sourceDirectory>
      <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/gen/java</outputDirectory>
      <testCases>false</testCases>
      <serverSide>true</serverSide>
      <subPackageByFileName>false</subPackageByFileName>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

After lots of fiddling around I noticed that these two beans cause this (actually just one of them):

```
  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean servletWs(ServletContext servletContext) {
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext);

    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/ws/*");
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servletRegistrationBean.addInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
    servletRegistrationBean.setName("general-dispatcher");

    return servletRegistrationBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean servletUi(ServletContext servletContext) {
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext);

    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/ui/*");
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servletRegistrationBean.setName("pagestuff-dispatcher");

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic welcomeFilter = servletContext.addFilter("WelcomeFilter", new WelcomeFilter("./ui/index"));
    welcomeFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), false, "/");

    return servletRegistrationBean;
  }
```

The magic line is

```
servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
```

If I comment it out Tomcat stops as expected. So why shouldn't I be doing this and how should I do it instead?

If you need further excerpts of the code or other info don't hesitate to ask.

*This is Spring-Boot 1.4.1 with embedded Tomcat*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I should post this without assuming that a lightning striking can hit me any second or the entire staff at Pivotal is banning me...

Anyway, I "solved" this by adding a method that determines whether or not the code is running in an integration test:

```
  public static boolean isInRunningITest() {
    return Stream.of(Package.getPackages())
        .map(Package::getName)
        .anyMatch(name -> StringUtils.startsWithAny(name, "org.springframework.test", "org.springframework.boot.test"));
  }
```

Obviously it checks for Spring and Spring-Boot, anything else is left out. So the remaining step was to wrap the `setLoadOnStartup()` in an `if ()`.

This works for me and is probably among the dirtiest things I've ever coded...